# show running docker containers nicely formatted

Tags: docker, linux

Default layout of output from  `docker ps` is somewhat unwieldy ... how to get a better presentation of all locally running docker containers from terminal on linux ?

For context below is output from `docker ps` as viewed from terminal for human consumption

[image]

Comment: pipe to `less -S`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docker ps -a |  grep -v Exited | cut -c1-$COLUMNS
```

Depending on desired columns this is a good starting point to obtain a nice display of all running containers for human consumption ... it auto handles when you resize terminal window using env var COLUMNS

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS           
0677a58056f3   loud_clamav/av                                      "/bootstrap.sh"          24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes (he
ee374532c1bb   localhost:5000/hygge/loudweb-enduser                "/usr/bin/supervisor…"   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes  
5546cd73ebcc   localhost:5000/hygge/loudweb-admin                  "/usr/bin/supervisor…"   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes  
5e7c55a950b1   mongo                                               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes  
505909fa4490   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu   "/opt/mssql/bin/nonr…"   30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes  
a1ea1d2882f5   localhost:5000/hygge/loudweb-dind/2204280434        "/usr/bin/supervisor…"   About an hour ago   Up 24 minutes  
4713b632a08f   tvial/docker-mailserver:latest                      "supervisord -c /etc…"   43 hours ago        Up 24 minutes  
010da9fc7fd5   registry:2.7.0                                      "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   43 hours ago        Up About an hou
o
```

the big benefit of above command is dynamically handles current size of your terminal where you executed the command ( notice the use of COLUMNS env var)

naturally you can create an alias as a shortcut to run this command just save below in your file `~/.bashrc`  which allows you to just type in  `dpss`

```
alias dpss='docker ps -a |  grep -v Exited | cut -c1-$COLUMNS ' #  truncate width shows driven by current terminal size ... to avoid line wrapping
```

Comment: Just to be certain, do the grep before the cut.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible alternative to using shell pipes, check out the [`--filter`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filter) and [`--format`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#format) options of `docker ps`. ([`--no-trunc`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#no-trunc) is also handy sometimes.)

For example, the output of `docker ps -a |  grep -v Exited | cut -c1-$COLUMNS` can be approximated by the following command:

`docker ps -a --filter 'status=running' --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Command}}\t{{.RunningFor}}\t{{.Status}}'`

('approximated' because filter expressions annoyingly don't support NOT-operations and `status=running` is not exactly the same as `NOT exited`. Plus you don't get the neat auto-truncation of columns.)

Downside is that you have to grapple with a new DSL (Go templates) that might not be as familiar as shell pipelines. On the plus side, `--format` allows you to shape the output in any way that you see fit, e.g.

```
$ docker ps --format '{{.Image}}: {{.Command}}'
netdata/netdata: "/usr/sbin/run.sh"
```